# How do we check number of records are loaded so far onto db from Kafka topic?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to load data from Kafka topic to Postgres using Jdbc sink connector . Now, how do we know the number of records are loaded so far into Postgres. As of now I keep on checking number of records in db using sql query. Is there any other way I can know about it?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Connect doesn't track this. I see nothing wrong with `SELECT COUNT(*)` on the table, however this doesn't exclude other processes writing to that table as well

Answer (score -1):

it is not possible in KAFKA. Because once you have sinked the records into the target DB, KAFKA is already done its job. But you can track number of records that you are updating using SINK Record Collections write into your local file or insert into a KAFKA State store.